# $\kappa< \kappa^ {\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$ in ZF

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

So in ZFC, we have [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)). An important corollary is, if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, then $\kappa< \kappa^ {\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$.

However, König's theorem is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice. So if we are working merely in ZF, I don't think we can prove $\kappa< \kappa^ {\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$ for infinite cardinals $\kappa$. (But correct me if I'm wrong.)

However, I was wondering if there is still an analougue of $\kappa< \kappa^ {\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$ for ZF if we strengthen the assumptions a little bit. Obviously it's false if $\kappa$ is infinite and $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ is finite, but what if we assume both $\kappa$ and $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ are infinite? Would this be strong enough, or do we need something stronger?

Edit: To clarify, the definition I'm using for $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ is the least ordertype of cofinal (i.e. unbounded in $\kappa$) subsets of $\kappa$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131450/discussion-on-question-by-pascals-wager-kappa-kappa-operatornamecf-ka).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cof}{\operatorname{cof}}$

The way to define cofinality in the question is ill-defined for non-well orderable cardinals.

We can change a bit the definition to be: $$\cof(\kappa)=\min\{α∈Ord\mid\text{There exists a partition $P$ of $κ$ such that }|P|=α, x\in P\implies|x|<κ\}$$
For well orderable $κ$, this is the same as the usual definition, but for non-well orderable $κ$ it is more interesting:

If $κ$ is [infinite Dedekind finite](http://cantorsattic.info/Dedekind_finite)([wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20181009165400/http://cantorsattic.info/Dedekind_finite) in case the link dies) then $κ$ is infinite but $\cof(κ)=2$ and indeed $κ<κ^{\cof(κ)}$

If [the reals are countable union of countable sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100717/zf-the-reals-are-the-countable-union-of-countable-sets-consistent) then $\cof(|\mathbb R|)=ω$ but here we have that both $\mathbb R$ and $\cof(\mathbb R)$ are infinites and yet $|\mathbb R|=2^ω=2^{ω×ω}=(2^ω)^ω=(2^ω)^{\cof(2^ω)}=|\mathbb R|^{\cof(|\mathbb R|)}$

Indeed if the reals are countable union of countable sets then König's theorem fails but both the reals and their cofinality are infinite

Comment: I don't think it's fair to restrict cofinality to ordinals. My feeling is that in general, the cofinality of a cardinal should be a filter of cardinals, so you can say what $\lambda\geq \operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ means, even if $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ is not necessarily a cardinal. Still, there are two distinct notions I can think of (by injections from and by surjections to cofinal subsets of $[\kappa]^{<\kappa}$), and in any case, I think the reals example shows that any sensible statement is independent of ZF.

Comment: @tomasz mind elaborate about how you define cofinality as a filter? I don't see how to extend the definition to include non well orderable cardinals without being kind of trivial (e.g. instead of taking the <-minimal ordinal, you take the class of cardinals that allow such partition)